# apps appear as Chrome extension and doesn't appear on google apps marketplace

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-apps-marketplace

Similar to this question After publishing my Google Apps app to the Chrome Webstore, it installs as an extension. I can't find my app on google apps marketplace. I use the correct manifest.json as in the google apps marketplace publish section of the developer page (https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing), But still doesn't appear until these two days. Can someone from google help me on this?

```
{  
  "manifest_version" : 2,  
  "name" : "myApp",  
  "version" : "1.1.1.1",  
  "description" : "upload the app",  
  "icons" : {  
      "128" : "icons/128x128-icon.png",  
      "16" : "icons/16x16-icon.png"  
  },  
  "container" : ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE", "GOOGLE_DRIVE"],  
  "api_console_project_id" : "123456789012"  
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Post your manifest.json here so we can help you verify that it is indeed a Chrome App.

Comment: @Marc, thanks for your reply. Here it is :  
    {    "manifest_version" : 2,  "name" : "myApp",  "version" : "1.1.1.1",  "description" : "upload the app",  "icons" : {  "128" : "icons/128x128-icon.png",  "16" : "icons/16x16-icon.png"  },  "container" : ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE", "GOOGLE_DRIVE"],  "api_console_project_id" : "123456789012"  }  . It is published as google chrome webstore extension app, but it doesn't appear on google apps marketplace.

Comment: That is not the manifest for a Chrome App. Your term "extension app" is confusing -- there are extensions and apps, and they are different things.

Comment: @Marc, This is the manifest.json as said in this link https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing. I didn't intend to put that in Chrome webstore, I intend to publish it as google apps marketplace, but it appears as extension in google chrome webstore and doesn't appear on google apps marketplace.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem. To publish the app in the new apps marketplace so it can only be installed by Google Apps domain admins we took the following steps:

1) Unpublish the old app and create a new app (didn't understand why this is needed but was suggested by Google - you only need to recreate the app once)

2) You can use the same manifest, but for the "container" section remove 'GOOGLE_DRIVE' (I believe there is currently an issue where including this makes the app go to the Chrome webstore). Note that removing GOOGLE_DRIVE will remove the app from the 'mini marketplace' that appears when you select the 'Open With' > 'Connect more apps' option when right clicking a file in Google Drive.

3) Include the following section in the manifest (where foo.bar is a url that must be opened when the app is launched):

```
"app": {
  "launch": {
    "web_url": "http://foo.bar"
  }
}
```

4) Publish the app - it should show a preview in the Google Apps Marketplace and will appear in this format: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-slate/ccnijgcacpbjachbddmjjinnkidkpaob

So example manifest that worked for us:

```
{  
  "manifest_version" : 2,  
  "name" : "myApp",  
  "version" : "1.1.1.1",  
  "description" : "upload the app",  
  "icons" : {  
      "128" : "icons/128x128-icon.png",  
      "16" : "icons/16x16-icon.png"  
  },  
  "container" : ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],  
  "api_console_project_id" : "123456789012"
  "app" : {
    "launch" : {
      "web_url" : "http://foo.bar"
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Facing same issue. This solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "app" to your mainfest. See https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#background.

```
Something like following, where http://foo.bar is apps web URL.
"app": {
  "launch": {
    "web_url": "http://foo.bar"
  }
}
```

If this doesn't work, try removing GOOGLE_DRIVE from the container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but either way always give me "This item is not an app" error message.

Comment: I am guessing we cannot convert an extension to an app.If not too much hassle can you try adding a new Chrome Item but make sure to include 'app': {...} in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm actually trying to upload it as google apps marketplace app, not as google chrome webstore app and I just followed the how to publish into google apps marketplace website https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing. thanks.

Comment: I got that. What I am suggesting is that the documentation on that page is likely outdated. It appears we need 'app' : {..} in the manifest for it to be published as an app. One quick way to confirm is by trying to publish a new app. Makes sense?

Comment: I have already done that and it's appeared on Google Chrome Webstore as an app (not extensions anymore). But how long that I need to wait to see it appeared on Google Apps Marketplace? Thanks.